# Epson printer with Swift cannot find symbol for arm64

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, precompiled-headers, epson

I receive the following error when I try build my project:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_Epos2Printer", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see 
invocation)
```

This is what my project navigator looks like:

[image]

Bridging header is like so:

```
#ifndef Bridging_Header_h
#define Bridging_Header_h


#import "ePOS2.h"
#import "ePOSEasySelect.h"


#endif /* Bridging_Header_h */
```

Build phase is like so:

[image]

And `Objective-C Bridging Header` is:

[image]

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

There's two possibilities. Either (1) you've forgotten to link the library that contains Epos2Printer function, or (2) you have linked it but it does not contain a slice for `arm64`.

If it's (1) linking to the ePOS SDK should solve the problem. It it's (2) you will need to obtain a copy of the library with `arm64` support.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem,
When run sample project, I find "libxml2.2.tbd" missing in my project.
After add missing file, error go away :))
Epson document didn't recommend this, so sad

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to open the project with *.xcworkspace, you need to add ExternalAccessory.framework reference. Like this image.

[image]